# Ruby spawned process listening on parent server port

Tags: ruby, fedora, puma, spawn

I am running a puma server ruby application on fedora 32. In my server I have certain calls which will spawn new long running processes for various reasons. I came across an issue where my spawned processes were running and *listening* on the same port as my server. This lead to issues with restarting my server on deploys as the server could not start because of processes listening on the desired port. How could this be possible? From my understanding when I spawn a process it should have completely different memory to the parent process, and share no file descriptors. My spawn command is simply

```
my_pid = Process.spawn(my_cmd, %i[out err] => log_file)
```

Ruby version 2.7.0

Edit: something I had overlooked in my deploy process and my original problem description, server restart is not an actual tear down and restart of a new process, but via signalling USR2 to the puma server (as described [here](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/restart.md))

Comment: `spawn` will call fork under the hood and thus will inherit a copy of the descriptors of your socket. So it's not as mysterious as it might sound at first. I can't give an exact explanation or resolution though.

Comment: Ok sure but then when exec is called won't these references be removed?

Comment: @NickHyland side question to understand the problem better: why aren't these long-running processes spawned from the main app shut down/restarted when the app itself gets redeployed? Are they fully independent from the main app so it is safe to keep them up and running even when the app itself gets changed?

Comment: Yeah they’re fully independent and need to stay running while server is restarted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found what is causing this. Seems to be an issue with [puma restart process](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/restart.md), which I was using. By restarting the server with a `USR2` signal, it changes the flags on the open fd for the socket.

```
[me@home puma_testing]$ cat /proc/511620/fdinfo/5
pos:    0
flags:  02000002
mnt_id: 10
[me@home puma_testing]$ kill -s USR2 511620
[me@home puma_testing]$ cat /proc/511620/fdinfo/5
pos:    0
flags:  02
mnt_id: 10
```

This was tested on fedora 32 using a very simple puma and sinatra setup like so:
`puma.rb`

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

rackup File.join(File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__)), './server.ru')

# https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/puma/Puma/DSL#prune_bundler-instance_method
# This allows us to install new gems with just a phased-restart. Otherwise you
# need to take the master process down each time.
prune_bundler

port 11111

environment 'production'

pidfile File.join(File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__)), '../', 'server.pid')

tag 'test'
```

And `server.ru` like so

```
require 'sinatra'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  get "/" do
    "Hello World!"
  end

  get "/spawn" do
    spawn "sleep 500"
  end
end

run App
```

Ran using bundler `bundle exec puma -C puma.rb`. Note you can use `/spawn` get request to test spawning a new process before and after restart to see if it is listening on the socket with `lsof -itcp:11111`

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround / solution will be to call [`fork`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Process.html#method-c-fork), close Puma's socket within the forked process and then call [`exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Process.html#method-c-exec), which [replaces the running process](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)... however, this workaround is limited to Unix systems. On windows you can probably achieve something similar using a more complicated approach.

Sadly, I am not sure how to close Puma's listening socket. Perhaps [this will helps](https://rubydoc.info/gems/puma/Puma/Runner#close_control_listeners-instance_method), but more likely than not there's some other trick to this.